# php artisan route:list not displayed as table

Tags: laravel-8

First of all, I'm new to Laravel. I got the followings after running "php artisan route:list", is it normal?

[image]

Here is everything in web.php:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "php artisan route:list" looking fine, It's a Laravel 9 new route:list console view. Link: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases#improved-route-list